# is it possible to open same application in different viewport

Tags: 12.04, unity, workspaces

i want to have same application opened in different viewport and i dont want to keep shifting between viewports just because an application is already opened in other viewport.

i really new in Ubuntu just recently moved from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You mean viewports not workspaces ;) Have a look at `devilspie` and `wmctrl`. Those seem to be the most found methods on google but I am unfamiliar with both.

Comment: oh yes my mistake , i am gona edit it, is it not possible to do this trick using CompizConfig

Comment: It might work if you change the executable to another name (firexox1, firefox2 and then open firefox1 in VP 1 and firefox2 in VP2) but that would be a rather inefficient method ;)